# Is Jailbreaking And Enabling Bluetooth File Transfer On iPhone 4 Financially Secure?

Tags: bluetooth, ios, jailbreak, sim, iphone

I want to use iPhone 4 for **sensitive information**. Will jailbreaking, downloading unofficial apps (not registered in Apple's App Store) and enabling Bluetooth file transfer cause a chance of sensitive data theft? Can unofficial app turn out to be malware?

Is *sim free* iPhone already jailbroken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Briefing

Jailbreaking is unofficial so no iphone comes jailbroken unless a individual have purposely installed it. If *sim-free iphone* is a *factory unlocked one* as you implied in a comment, there is no direct relation and it does not come jailbroken at all. And never will.

As Brad said, even official apps have a good chance to be malware. But, granted, "unofficial" ones do have higher chance.

I'd say the biggest risk you have on jailbreaking, though, is leaving it open for some exploits. Two of the most common ones would be ssh root alpine and breaking through the lockcode.

And with not jailbreaking the biggest risk you have is connecting on unsecure wifi.

With jailbreaking you have the possibility of arming yourself with more tools both for exposing and fixing security holes so it all depends on how savy you are.

## Advice

I would not use anything I don't deeply understand to store sensitive information, and it's not jailbreaking the main issue here. If you lose your iPhone, or someone steal it with the intent to steal information from it, you're basically screwed - specially if it's not jailbroken with heavy tweaks and customizations because it makes it all the easier to find exploits.

That's why Windows has so many malwares - because it's heavily used worldwide and most people will use it with default configurations - so it's way spread out with more people trying to break it and sharing information on how to do it.

I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

> Will jailbreaking, downloading unofficial apps (not registered in Apple's App Store) and enabling Bluetooth file transfer cause a chance of sensitive data theft?

There's a chance, but if you download from verified sources and check the repository you're going to be downloading from (google searches, etc.) you should be okay.  There's always a risk, but as with any risk, if you're vigilant about things you'll be fine.

> Is sim free iPhone already jailbroken?

If you're talking about an iPhone without the sim card, no, that doesn't mean that the phone is jailbroken already.  It just means it's the phone without the sim card.  iPhones have removable sim cards in them.

Comment: SIM-free usually implies that it is not locked to a network provider, meaning that you can put a SIM card from any network in it. This is often lumped in with jailbreaking as it is sometimes necessary to jailbreak in order to unlock. But it's also possible to just go to the Apple Store and buy an unlocked iPhone in many countries.

Comment: Sim-free is phone that was never locked. It was not meant for specific cellular network company and has general setting that are meant to work with any cellular network company.

Without sim card? That means no obligation in cellular network company and that phone can work without sim? Confused a little...